# Expected to see 1 array(s), for inputs ['dense_1'] but instead got the following list of 300 arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to feed my data into CNN but there seems to be an error with my input shape. I am trying to feed the CNN to be able to recognise the first names and make predictions. I have to delete 3 convolutional layers to reduce the code before posting here.

How can I solve it, please?

Code:

```
# split data into train and testing
train = create_label.data[:1200]
test = create_label.data[1200:]


# x train in 0 index. -1 calculates the x-train number of train 50, 50 is the image shape.
# 1 is grayscale image
X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, 50, 50, 1)
print(f'X_train shape is {X_train.shape}')

# y train in 1 index -1 calculates the y-train number of train 50, 50 is the image shape
y_train = [i[1] for i in train]
X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, 50, 50, 1)
print(f'X_test shape is {X_test.shape}')
y_test = [i[1] for i in test]



# DNN
# input_shape = input_data(shape=[50,50,1])
model = Sequential()

# 1 - Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(32,5, padding='same', input_shape=(50, 50,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))

# 2nd Convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(64,5, padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))



# Flattening
model.add(Flatten())


# Fully connected layer 2nd layer
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))

model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))

opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Error:

````
 raise ValueError('Error when checking model ' + exception_prefix +
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), for inputs ['dense_1'] but instead got the following list of 300 arrays: [array([[0],
       [0],
       [1]]), array([[0],
       [1],
       [0]]), None, array([[0],
       [1],
       [0]]), array([[0],
       [0],
       [1]]), array([[0],
       [0],
       [1]]), arr...```
````

Comment: check in the summary what is `dense_1`

Comment: I think your `softmax` and `relu` activation functions, along with their placements, are the issue. Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish but maybe swap them? And are you sure you need that second `BatchNormalization()`? Also unless your labels are one-hot encoded, your loss function needs to be sparse categorical cross entropy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have 500 faces of 3 people each in the dataset and trying to use CNN to predict which face and name. Will follow up on your suggestion and let you know how it goes.

Comment: In that case, your Dense layers are set up incorrectly. Softmax comes last, that's your classifier.